# Create column dataset based on other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
name                surname 
Mr. William John    Mellors
Miss. Wendla Maria  Heininen
Mrs. Sandra         Gonzalez
```

It depends on whether the "name" column says "Mrs" "Miss" "Ms" I have to assign one value or another to my new column titled "title"

For example for "MS" , is married men, for "Miss" women not married, or "Mrs" married women.

Here is the output dataset.

```
 name                surname      title
Mr. William John    Mellors       married men
Miss. Wendla Maria  Heininen      not married women
Mrs. Sandra         Gonzalez      married women
```

I dont know if there is a function to do it, or using ifelse and assing it to my first dataframe.

Code not working,

```
#dataframe loading
titanic <- read.table("C:/Users/sergio.urrea/Downloads/titanic.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

titanic$title<-ifelse(titanic$name="Master","Hombre soltero",
                    ifelse(titanic$name="Miss","Mujer soltera"))
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service. Please read [ask] and [mcve]! Nethertheless welcome to SO!

Comment: use '==' instead of '=' for logical comparison

Comment: ofc I have tried it, is hard, I am learning about R and graphs and it's hard for the first time

Comment: try to explore grep function too to check whether a name has mr or miss in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data.frame is called "df"

```
df[grepl("^Mr.$",df$name),3] = "married men"
df[grepl("^Miss.$",df$name),3] = "not married women"
df[grepl("^Mrs.$",df$name),3] = "married women"
```

You can also refer to column 3 explicitly and protect those "."

```
df[grepl("^Mr\\.$",df$name),]$title = "married men"
df[grepl("^Miss\\.$",df$name),]$title = "not married women"
df[grepl("^Mrs\\.$",df$name),]$title = "married women"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `str_detect()` from `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
    library(stringr)

    df = data.frame(name = c("Mr. William John", "Miss. Wendla Maria", "Mrs. Sandra"), 
                        surname  = c(" Mellors", "Heininen", "Gonzalez")) 


        df %>% mutate(title = ifelse(str_detect(name, "Mr."), "married men",
                                     ifelse(str_detect(name, "Mrs."), "married woman",  "not married woman")))

                   name  surname             title
    1   Mr. William John  Mellors       married men
    2 Miss. Wendla Maria Heininen not married woman
    3        Mrs. Sandra Gonzalez       married men
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your ifelse method:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("Mr. William John", "Miss. Wendla Maria", "Mrs. Sandra"), 
                surname  = c(" Mellors", "Heininen", "Gonzalez"))
# Set default value for *title* column
df$title <- 'married man'
# If name starts with 'Miss', then it is not married woman
df$title <- ifelse(grepl('^Miss. ', df$name), 'not married woman', df$title)
# If name starts with 'Mrs', then it is married woman
df$title <- ifelse(grepl('^Mrs. ', df$name), 'married woman', df$title)
```